# Difference between CommonsHTTPTransportSender and org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender

Tags: https, apache-axis, wso2-esb

What is the difference between the 2 transport sender.  When I invoke an HTTP URL from an axis service (deployed in wso2 esb), with CommonsHTTPTransportSender as transportSender for https channel, service works fine, where as with PassThroughHttpSSLSender as transportSender throws exception

```
AxisEngine Message Receiver not found for AxisOperation: {oauth2.identity.carbon.wso2.org}validate org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Message Receiver not found for AxisOperation: {oauth2.identity.carbon.wso2.org}validate
```

What is the difference, and how would I get over this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I do not know the difference between those different transport senders, but the error was due to an issue in the service code, which was through some exception.  When I handled it properly, this issue did not arise with either of them.